# Duplicates in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on http://rubyquiz.com/quiz28.html and am almost done except for one little bug.

In the following: prompts is an array, which for arguments sake is `["one", "two", "three", "three", "four]`

```
  def ask_reader(prompts)
    @answers = {}
    for p in prompts
      puts "Give me a #{p}"
      @answers[p] = gets.chomp
    end
  end
```

This works fine and I get an answers hash with the corresponding answers, except that the second answers[p] will override the first one, thus leaving me with only one value for "three". Is there good 'ruby' way of solving this? Thanks.

Comment: How would you expect an algorithm to generate unique hash codes for identical objects? You are using the wrong data structure if you need this ability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two obvious options:

Cross-reference the original prompts array with the answers array by means of `Array#zip`:

```
def ask_reader(prompts)
  prompts.inject([]) do |accu, p|
    puts "Give me a #{p}"
    accu << gets.chomp
    accu
  end
end

["one", "two", "two"].zip(["1", "2", "3"])
# => [["one", "1"], ["two", "2"], ["two", "3"]]
```

Then iterate like so:

```
[["one", "1"], ["two", "2"], ["two", "3"]].each do |(prompt, response)|
  puts "#{prompt}: #{response}"
end
```

Or, use a `Hash` with `Array` values.

```
def ask_reader(prompts)
  prompts.inject({}) do |accu, p|
    puts "Give me a #{p}"
    (accu[p] ||= []) << gets.chomp
    accu
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first solution (as It was the most understandable).

Answer (score 4):

how about a map of prompts to lists of values, like this:

prompt1 => ["one"]
prompt2 => ["two"]
prompt3 => ["three", "three"]
prompt4 => ["four"]

Answer (score 0):

What about using as keys some sort of wrapper objects with internal field 'prompt' ?

Answer (score 0):

more simple way.

```
a = %w[one two three four]
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] =  a.find_index(key)+1}
p h["one"]
p h["three"]
```